# In an ETAP simulation, why do I get different tripping sequences depending on whether I simulate a short-circuit before or after a specific CT?

Tags: simulation, short-circuit, power-engineering

I have a simulation of a relatively simple power system on ETAP. Relays are selective with each other in the Star view, however when I simulate a short circuit, the sequence of tripping that I get behaves in a manner that I do not understand. When I simulate a short circuit right before a specific CT, the sequence of tripping that I obtain is different from that of when I simulate the short-circuit right after the CT. What's happening?
[image]

Comment: Need schematics to be able to answer. Please expand acronyms

Comment: Is the short circuit current different for the two cases? I haven't used ETAP myself, but do CTs send signals to relays, or do relays get the information from the simulations directly? I.e. do relays and breakers work even without any CTs/VTs? I agree with RusselH. Can you please share the relevant parts of your system and explain which relays trips, the SC results, time/current plot if relevant etc.?

Comment: @StewieGriffin ; I don't see any reason why the short circuit current would be different for the two cases. Relays and breakers must be associated to CTs and VTs in order to trip.

Comment: I added schematics @RussellH

Comment: I _believe_ this is fairly simple. The current through the highlighted CT is different, so you get different tripping sequences. Why would you expect the same results? Is there SC contribution from both sides? Does green X mean tripped relay?